# Vue Router - redirect to the same route does not triggers afterEach() guard

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm usign vue-router for a Single Page Application and I've implemented several guards to use into the router itself. I've noticed that if a guard redirects me to the same page where I actually am, the `afterEach()` function does not tiggers.

Let me give You an example. Imagine you have the following flow:
I'm in the **Login page**; I use my credentials and I'm redirected to the **Home page**. Here I click the 'back' button to go back to the Login page, but a guard, that checks if I'm already logged in, redirects me back to the **Home page**.
In this scenario, the `afterEach()` function does not triggers.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This solution won't work for all cases, but it could work for the example you mentioned if you implement an additional manual navigation guard in your router's `beforeEach` hook.

Assume you have the following code where a user tries to navigate from `/home` to `/login` and ends up back on `/home` without the `afterEach` hook firing:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (user.isAuthenticated() && to.path === '/login') {
    return next('/home')
  }
  return next()
})

router.afterEach(() => {
  // some logic
})
```

Refactor this to:

```
const afterEach = function() {
  // some logic
}

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (user.isAuthenticated() && to.path === '/login') {
    if (from.path === '/home') {
      afterEach()
    }
    return next('/home')
  }
  return next()
})

router.afterEach(afterEach)
```